# M2 integration with PowerReviews Enterprise edition

Tags: magento2

I have to implement integration between M2 and PowerReviews Enterp. Edition and online resources are just about non-existed. Short of the official PR docs, are there any other resources that would be helpful in getting started with this?

Comment: If I remember, you only need to add some JS for PowerReviews and manage some product exports to them

Comment: ... for the "Express" edition - yes, for the Enterprise it's whole different ballgame.

Comment: Ok so keep in touch directly with PR, and their docs. You will be able to build your own module integration so.